# Which action precedes the `woocommerce_save_product_variation` action hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Can anyone tell me which action precedes the `woocommerce_save_product_variation` action hook?

I'm trying to save old price and quantity before updating product variation

Answer (score 1):

In [meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3377c60c5e5602a4c82b6ef43b7b48b9c895f9ad/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php) line 530-541 you can find

```php
/**
 * Set variation props before save.
 *
 * @param object $variation WC_Product_Variation object.
 * @param int $i
 * @since 3.8.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', $variation, $i );

$variation->save();

do_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', $variation_id, $i );
```

---

So `woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object` action precedes `woocommerce_save_product_variation`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this hook not fires by clicking "Save Changes" button on WooCommerce / Products / Edit Product - Edit selected variation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object`

```php
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'prefix_previous_variation_price', 10, 1);
function prefix_previous_variation_price($variation) {
   $previous_price = $variation->get_price();
}
```

To find this kind of hook you can look woocommerce source files.
For example for this: I search the `woocommerce_save_product_variation` on http://hookr.io/. I saw that this hook was called in `class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php`. Then I take a look to this file and I find `woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object` hook who are called just before `$variation->save();`

Take a look here:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ac9f83d7724b889a1740d651eb4cd8ac5bb5b4f2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L537

Comment: Sorry, I found a problem .. and the problem is in the WooCommerce version. My version is 3.8.1 and that hook `woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object` is introduced in version 4.0.0

Comment: that is the last option, because of all other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with `woocommerce_variation_header`.

This hook will be activated for each product variation. Therefore, you need to have a private class-level associative array, where you will store (for you) important information from  product (variation), e.g. price, stock quantity, etc.

After that, save that array in db, ie. wp_options, with a specific name.

When you call `woocommerce_save_product_variation`, then also call array that you already saved for same variation from `wp_options` and finally then compare the data.

That’s what I needed but a detour and reason for this approach is that I had to stay on the same old version of WooCommerce.

Thank you all for participating!